# sanitize_post_field() not accepting by PHPCS why?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpcs

```
$template_html = sanitize_post_field('template_content_html',$_POST['template_content_html'], $post_id, 'db' );
```

I'm saving some HTML in post meta but i don't want lose any html while sanitizing but this  **sanitize_post_field()**  actually not accepting by phpcs why is there missing something?

I was looking for saving html in post meta

Comment: "sanitize_post_field() actually not accepting by phpcs" - By that do you mean you are running PHP Code Sniffer against your code and getting an error/warning? If so, what error is it reporting?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes I was running PHP Code Sniffer against my code.

Comment: Are you able to answer the second part of my comment?

Comment: @ChrisHaas PHPCS was giving ERROR | Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable:
     |       | $_POST[template_content_html']
     |       | (WordPress.Security.ValidatedSanitizedInput.InputNotSanitized) 
but I've unslashed and sanitized

Comment: First, `sanitize_post_field` probably doesn't really do what you expect it to. The field you are sanitizing isn't one of the known/built-in ones, so WordPress can't apply any default logic to it, and basically does nothing with it, thus not sanitizing anything. You might instead want `wp_kses` or `wp_kses_post`, however you should definitely make sure to also escape on output, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks I'll check that for sure!!